# Editable cells in ReadOnly Columns DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is populated from data in a DB, but not with a DataSource.  I get a row from my DB and add a row to my DataGridView on init.

My question is, I have a column that is ReadOnly, but sometimes, there is no data in the DB for this column, and in this case I want the user to be able to add it, but not overwrite the data if the info came from the DB.

How do I make a single cell in a column Editable, but not the column?

I.E. Allow this ---

```
            Col1        Col2 (ReadOnly)                    Col1       Col2 (ReadOlny)
 Row1       A           Can't Change      -->   Row1       J          Can't Change
 Row2       B                                   Row2       B          I added this!
 Row3       C           No Change               Row3       T          No Change
```

But not this ---

```
            Col1        Col2 (ReadOnly)                    Col1       Col2 (ReadOlny)
 Row1       A           Can't Change      -->   Row1       J          OOPS!  
 Row2       B                                   Row2       B          I added this!
 Row3       C           No Change               Row3       T          Not allowed!
```

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/943862/897326).

Comment: Set the ReadOnly property of the cell to false if it's null or empty, preferably as you insert the row into the grid. If the column's ReadOnly status is overriding the cell, change it to false as well and let the cell drive it's own ability to be edited instead of a blanket case on the whole column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to create the illusion of a read-only column.

Rather than setting the Column to Read-Only, you could simply modify each cell within the column as read only where the cell value is not equal to null or String.Empty. This will allow the user to edit those cells that are blank and protect your data.

Just loop through the DataGridViewRow's :-

```
Foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
   If(!row.Cells[2].Value.Equals(null) || !row.Cells[2].Value.Equals(String.Empty))
     {
        row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
     }
}
```

Pardon for any Syntax issues, I've done this off the top of my head.

Comment: The EditingControlShowing event is not triggered on a ReadOnly Column :/

Comment: Solution is to keep the column readOnly = false and mod the cells individually.  Same goes for making one cell in a column have a dropdown, or anything else :)  Thanks!