# Disabling editing in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I want to disable the editing on the `DataGridView`, it seems to work when I used this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

But when I get back on the menu form then go back to the form where the `DataGridView` is, it can now be edit. I only define

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

to this form. And I don't know whats the problem. Can someone help? Thanks.

Here's my code on the button going to the menu

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
this.Hide();
menu.ShowDialog();
```

and my button going back to the DataGrid:

```
FrmList frmlist = new FrmList();
frmlist.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Hi did you tried this.close()? on frmlist rather than hiding it? With the help of that your events will be rebinded

Comment: doesn't change the output sir

Comment: @marc_s a winform sir

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Why don't you try setting the `ReadOnly` property to **True** in the Properties window of the DataGridView?

**Edit:**

Double click on the form and in the design window, select the DataGridView and open the Properties tab. Scroll down through the properties and you will see the `ReadOnly` option. Change it's value to **True**.

You were setting the `ReadOnly` property in the `CellContentClick` event which will be executed only when user clicks on the grid cells. So, when you create a new object of the form like this,

```
FrmList frmlist = new FrmList();
```

it will just create a new instance of the form with the `Properties` set in the designer. Since the `ReadOnly` property is set to false by default and the code you wrote to set it to true has not executed, the DataGridView will be editable.

Comment: Is that the ReadOnlyChanged? it is not a boolean sir

Comment: that solves the problem :) is that different from just coding ReadOnly?

Answer (score 3):

> Ref:

[DataGridView read only cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943823/datagridview-read-only-cells)

```
this.dgridvwMain.Rows[index].Cells["colName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: use DataGridView.CellEnter property

Answer (score 3):

add this to your code:

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

or you can change Read Only property in designer mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form is reinitialized on navigation. You can set a breakpoint in the constructor. This depends on your navigation service, or how ever it is implemented. In this case you can set the `ReadOnly` Flag to the last value on initialization or implement it as singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Make the the entire DataGridView read only.
For more information visit [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void Button8_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewBand band in dataGridView.Columns)
    {
        band.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```